# Why Maven requires same version of different dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I'm a student with quite some experience in Java but totally new to Maven.

I was trying to implement a RESTful service provider and client with jersey-server and jersey-client. Both also depends on jersey-json, to make use of automatic conversion between POJO and JSON. Both of them also depend on a service model I implemented myself, where the POJO definition resides.

However, the code doesn't work for me. I spent quite a few hours looking for solutions everywhere on the Internet. It turns out the reason of the failure is that I accidentally specified version of jersey-server and jersey-client as 1.14, but jersey-json as 1.9.1.

The server doesn't work at the beginning, but at some point suddenly starts working. (I have no idea how this happened.) The client never worked until I change jersey-json version to 1.14.

Why do I need to have the same version for these different dependencies?

Comment: because the different version may have different APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because one depends on the other or otherwise has a compatibility issue. This is what dependency management is all about. Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see exactly how these libraries relate to each other.

In this case, it seems Jersey libraries are all released together as a "bundle" - and you need to use the versions from those bundles together.  See: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/chapter_deps.html

Note that this is an attribute of the Jersey libraries, not Maven.

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree` gives different output when I specify 1) 1.14 for both 2) specify 1.14 and 1.9.1 for each. But these different output are only different in version numbers of some dependencies, and doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: There is no one-size fits all answer to this. Dependency management / libraries breaking when the wrong version of another library is used is a common problem in software.  It seems you have discovered that certain Jersey components have to be from the same release "package."

Answer (score 1):

Often different jars from the same distribution are tested together and given the same version number.

If you try to mix different versions it might work, or it might not, as its not a combination which was intended or tested.

Comment: What does it mean by 'same distribution'?

Comment: "Distribution" set of software artifacts (libraries, documentation, samples) that are packaged together and assigned a version number.